# How can i extend a public variable from Multiboxtracker to another class?(Tensorflow Lite)

Tags: java, android, tensorflow

I am trying to get the title from Multiboxtracker class to Another Class Like Gettitle but i can't seem to be able to extend the public variable. Please help me out.

```
the code in Multiboxtracker.java

private void processResults(final List<Recognition> results) {


      screenRects.add(new Pair<Float, RectF>(result.getConfidence(), detectionScreenRect));
      ///Tracking the result title;
      _title = result.getTitle();

      if (detectionFrameRect.width() < MIN_SIZE || detectionFrameRect.height() < MIN_SIZE) {
        logger.w("Degenerate rectangle! " + detectionFrameRect);
        continue;
      }

      rectsToTrack.add(new Pair<Float, Recognition>(result.getConfidence(), result));
    }

    trackedObjects.clear();
    if (rectsToTrack.isEmpty()) {
      logger.v("Nothing to track, aborting.");
      return;
    }


    }
  }



Gettitle.java Class code is 

public class GetDetectedObject extends MultiBoxTracker{
    public String title;
    public GetDetectedObject(){
        super(new MultiBoxTracker(this));
        title = _title;

    }
}
```

Ive made a public variable at the start of the class

Still Gettitle class cant extend Multiboxtracker class.